# Using Parallaxing for a 2D game in unity Understanding the Z axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, parallax

i'm using parallaxing for a 2D game in unity and basically, I'm moving the position of the backgrounds on the x axis whenever the camera moves (The camera moves right or left following the character). I'm having trouble understanding what this line means `parallaxScales[i] = backgrounds[i].position.z * -1;` Doesn't the z position have to do with depth? What exactly does it mean when you say position.z * -1 or position.z * 5. Its not affecting the actual depth of the backgrounds ive been using in the game (since they are moving left and right). So what exactly does it mean. why use the Z axis?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Parallaxing : MonoBehaviour {


public Transform [] backgrounds;    
private float [] parallaxScales;   
public float smoothing = 1f;      

private Transform cam;             
private Vector3 previousCamPos;    


void Awake () 

{
    cam = Camera.main.transform; 
}

void Start ()

{
    previousCamPos = cam.position;
    parallaxScales = new float[backgrounds.Length]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++)  
    {
        parallaxScales[i] = backgrounds[i].position.z * -1;

    }
}

void Update () 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < backgrounds.Length; i++)

    {

        float parallax = (previousCamPos.x - cam.position.x) * parallaxScales[i];

        float backgroundTargetPosX = backgrounds[i].position.x + parallax;   


        Vector3 backgroundTargetPos = new Vector3 (backgroundTargetPosX, backgrounds[i].position.y, backgrounds[i].position.z);


        backgrounds[i].position = Vector3.Lerp (backgrounds[i].position, backgroundTargetPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    previousCamPos = cam.position; 
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, 'z' has to do with the depth, and when you create your layers, each layer is stacked before or after the others (you change the z depth). For the parallax, you push the z depth far enough back that you can make it move faster/slower based on _how far_ back you had pushed it. The orthographic camera won't show the depth, but you can still use it to calculate how fast that background moves compared to all your foreground layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Parallaxing class is using the z value of the backgrounds to control the amount of parallax that gets applied to them. e.g. the higher the z the more movements happens to that background when the camera moves. Using the gameObjects Z value to control parallax is convinient because it allows you to easily see in the editor how much parallax will be applied to each object, and it doesn't require a custom script to be added to each object.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. When I multiplied a number to the z value, it doesn't  seem like it actually changes anything in Unity's scene editor. Now I can tell that changing it in the script or adjusting it manually in the scene editor actually does the same thing